# How do I call a function when I make a post request at Python?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I programmed using the django rest framework.
Since DRF is CRUD automatic, I created a view as shown below.

```
class PostViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
  permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly]
  serializer_class = PostSerializer
  queryset = AllfindPost.objects.all()
```

By the way, I would like to call the following functions when I make a post request.

```
def send_fcm_notification(ids, title, body):

    url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send'

    headers = {
        'Authorization': 'key=',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; UTF-8',
    }

    content = {
        'registration_ids': '',
        'notification': {
            'title': 'title',
            'body': 'body'
        }
    }

    requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(content), headers=headers)
```

What should I do?

Comment: Have you tried overriding the `post` methods of your viewset? Like `create` https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#viewset-actions

Comment: I'm sorry. I've just looked at the document and tried, but I don't know how to approach it. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Call your function after post request.

```
def call_my_function():
    pass

class PostViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
  permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly]
  serializer_class = PostSerializer
  queryset = AllfindPost.objects.all() 

    """
    Create a model instance.
    """
    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        #call your function Eg.
        call_my_function()
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It was very helpful.